# Return to ajax with while loop through PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have got this ajax

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '../connect.php',
                        data: "OrB=" + ajaxsend+"&&IOr="+i,
                        success: function(data)
                        { 
                             var x = $.parseJSON(data);
                             var el='<div class="CommentsAw Comment_Hs">\
                                      <img src="../users/'+x[0]+'">\
                                      <span>'+x[1]+'</span>\
                                      <span class="s2">'+x[2]+'</span>\
                                    </div>'
                                    $(".F_W_comments").html().remove();
                                    $(".F_W_comments").html(el);
                        }
        });
```

and php

```
if (isset($_GET['OrB'])) {
        $OB=$_GET['OrB'];
        $I=$_GET['IOr'];
        if ($OB=='OO') {
            $OB='`Date` ASC';
        }else if ($OB=='No') {
            $OB='`Date` DESC';
        }
        $query=$con->query("SELECT id,comment FROM uploads WHERE Rand='$I'");
        $row=$query->fetch_row();
        $Commentsq=$con->query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM comments WHERE Post_id='$row[0]' ORDER BY $OB LIMIT 4) AS sub ORDER BY `DATE` ASC") or die($con->error);
        while ($CommentRow=$Commentsq->fetch_row()) {
                $CommenterPp=$con->query("SELECT Profile_pic FROM user_opt WHERE Username='$CommentRow[3]'");        
                $CommenterPicture=$CommenterPp->fetch_row();
                $CommenterPp=$con->query("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Id='$CommentRow[3]'");        
                $CommenterName=$CommenterPp->fetch_row();
                echo json_encode(array($CommenterPicture,$CommenterName,$CommentRow));             
        }
    }
```

But it gives me error in console like this one

```
VM654:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 107
[["5734919677561.jpg"],["Murad"],["1842","3","21","1","2016-05-08 21:56:52"]]                    
                [["5734919677561.jpg"],["Murad"],["1843","GOodm","21","1","2016-05-08 21:56:54"]]                    
                [["5734919677561.jpg"],["Murad"],["1845","re","21","1","2016-05-08 21:56:54"]]                    
                [["5734919677561.jpg"],["Murad"],["1844","re","21","1","2016-05-08 21:56:54"]]
```

What i want is connect.php to get data from database and then pass it to ajax.
But the result was nothing probably bcause there is some error in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing several json-encoded strings does not mean a **valid** json.

What you need to do is `json_encode` your data and `echo` it **once**.

```
$commenters = array();    // result array
while ($CommentRow=$Commentsq->fetch_row()) {
    $CommenterPp=$con->query("SELECT Profile_pic FROM user_opt WHERE Username='$CommentRow[3]'");        
    $CommenterPicture=$CommenterPp->fetch_row();
    $CommenterPp=$con->query("SELECT Username FROM users WHERE Id='$CommentRow[3]'");        
    $CommenterName=$CommenterPp->fetch_row();
    $commenters[] = array($CommenterPicture,$CommenterName,$CommentRow);             
}
// while loop over
echo json_encode($commenters);
```

And in your js you should iterate over an array of objects, not a simple object, for example:

```
success: function(data) {
    var x = $.parseJSON(data);
    for (var k in x) {
        console.log(x[k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the data in the arrays for a moment, the resulting JSON was structured like this:

```
[][][][]
```

That's not valid JSON.  The parser expects a single object or array, not several arrays concatenated together like that.

Instead of outputting the response in the loop, build the total response and output it *once* after the loop.  Basically create an empty array before the `while` loop in PHP, then push elements onto the array within the loop, then echo the JSON-encoded array after the loop.

My PHP is very rusty, but in PHP-ish pseudo-code it would be structured like this:

```
$result = array();
while ($CommentRow=$Commentsq->fetch_row()) {
    // other code...
    $result[] = array($CommenterPicture,$CommenterName,$CommentRow);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: @TomOdell: It's not uncommon for similar answers to be given simultaneously on Stack Overflow.  We don't really coordinate with each other.

Comment: I know i am just saying that it will more fair to accept his answer